# How can I get this function to take in the id of an array element, then dispatch an action? MERN stack

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, mern

This component's purpose is to render a div with the details of each appointment that occurs later than today's date. The user should then be able to fill in the details in the input fields, and press submit. Once submitted, I'm trying to dispatch a redux action, and I need it to take in the id of the specific appointment div that the submit button is clicked on.

I can't seem to get the handleSubmit function to work properly. I can't tell if I'm passing in the appointment._id wrong into the button's onClick handler, or if I'm bringing it into the handleSubmit function wrong, or something else entirely. Notice there are two _id, one for the specific appointment from the appointments array, and a _id from the user being passed into the component from its parent.

Does anyone have any ideas how to get it to work properly?

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import { confirmAppointment } from '../../../actions/appointment'

const ConfirmAppointment = ({user}) => {

    const dispatch = useDispatch()

    const { appointments, _id } = user?.result

    const today = new Date()
    
    const [reasonForMassage, setReasonForMassage] = useState('')

    const formData = {
        reasonForMassage
    }

    // SET UP AN ONCLICK FOR EACH BUTTON TO SUBMIT IT'S OWN DISPATCH TO UPDATE APPOINTMENT 

    const handleSubmit = (e, appointmentId) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        console.log(appointmentId, reasonForMassage)
        //update appointment with the appointment id
        dispatch(confirmAppointment(_id, appointmentId, formData))
    }

    return (
        appointments?.length !== 0 ? (
            <div style={{marginTop: '3em'}}>
                <h4>Upcoming Appointments</h4>
                    {appointments && appointments?.map((appointment) => (
                        new Date(appointment?.date) >= today ? (                  
                            <div style={{marginBottom: '3em'}} key={appointment._id} >
                                <table className="ui table">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>Date</th>
                                            <th>Time</th>
                                            <th>Duration</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>{appointment?.date}</td>
                                            <td>{appointment?.time}</td>
                                            <td>{appointment?.duration}</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                                <form className="ui form" >
                                    <div className="ui fields">
                                        <div className="ui field">
                                            <label>Reason for booking massage:</label>
                                            <input type="text" value={reasonForMassage} onChange={(e)=>setReasonForMassage(e.target.value)}/>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="ui field">
                                            <h5>I give consent to massage the following areas:</h5>
                                            <div>
                                                <input type="checkbox" />
                                                <label>Glutes</label>
                                                <input type="checkbox" />
                                                <label>Abdomen</label>
                                                <input type="checkbox" />
                                                <label>Chest</label>
                                                <input type="checkbox" />
                                                <label>Inner thighs</label>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="ui field">
                                            <label>Are there any other areas you would not like to be massaged?</label>
                                            <input type="text" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <button onClick={()=>handleSubmit(appointment?._id)} className="ui button">Confirm Appointment</button>
                                </form>                                
                            </div>
                            ) : (                              
                                <div></div>
                            )
                        ))}                 
            </div>
        ) : (
            <div>
                No upcoming appointments
            </div>
        )
        
    )
}


export default ConfirmAppointment
```

Comment: You are calling `handleSubmit(appointment?._id)`, but the signature is `const handleSubmit = (e, appointmentId) => {}`

Comment: It won't let me put appointment.id into the parameters (ie. const handleSubmit = (e, appointment?._id) = {}). How can I get appointment._id from the array element to the function?

Comment: This question is answered for you, but to advance in react it's imperative to understand the fundamentals of programming, like how functions are declared and invoked and how parameters are assigned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change button's onClick function from

```
 <button
                onClick={() => handleSubmit(appointment?._id)}
                className='ui button'
            >
                Confirm Appointment
            </button>
```

to

```
  <button
                onClick={e => handleSubmit(e, appointment?._id)}
                className='ui button'
            >
                Confirm Appointment
            </button>
```

Comment: Ah of course! Thank you :)